# Generating thumbnails of files using remote URL. Is it even possible?

Tags: ios, swift, image, imageview

I am trying to generate thumbnails of files from remote URL, meaning I do not want to download those files and save them on device before showing thumbnails. I've tried for PDF and DOCX files, but what I get is a blank white image (get no error). Here is the code:

```
func generateThumbnail(completion: @escaping (UIImage) -> Void) {
    let size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
    
    let request = QLThumbnailGenerator.Request(fileAt: fileUrl,
                                               size: size,
                                               scale: scale,
                                               representationTypes: .all)
    
    let generator = QLThumbnailGenerator.shared
    generator.generateRepresentations(for: request) { thumbnail, _, error in
        if let thumbnail = thumbnail {
            completion(thumbnail.uiImage)
        } else if let error = error {
            print("Error: ", error)
        }
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or is it even possible to create those thumbnails from a remote URL, since I haven't found anything about that in documentation?

Comment: You should clarify your question, because you sated you don't want to download the original image from which you want to generate a thumbnail image. How would you do this _on the device_, if you don't have the original image? Answering the question in your title, well, might have a solution which is implemented on the server.